# Display multiple articles

Tags: joomla3.0

I'm wanting to create a news page which would consist of many articles, is there a way to display multiple articles on a page with the most recent article displayed at the top of the page?

Answer (score -1):

you can create a new menu for multiple article show on a page.
select menu type as category blog layout.